# Swift extra argument when initialising

Tags: ios, swift, object, ios8

I'm trying to create an app that saves data to CloudKit, I have that all sorted but when trying to initialise a new object I get an Extra Argument when initialising error.

Code with error:

```
func submitTask(){
    var task: Task
    task = CloudKitTask(task: Task){
        task.shortDescription = self.txtShortDesc.text!
        task.type = self.txtType.text!
        task.reminder = self.txtReminder.text!
        task.priority = self.txtPriority.text!
        task.dueTime = self.txtDueTime.text!
        task.dueDate = self.txtDueDate.text!
        task.completed = "False"
        task.className = self.txtClass.text!
        task.additionalDetails = self.txtDetails.text
    }
    print(task)
}
```

Error: Extra argument 'task' in call on the task = CloudK... line

Task Class:

```
protocol Task {
var id: String? { get }
var shortDescription: String { get set }
var className: String { get set }
var type: String { get set }
var dueDate: String { get set }
var dueTime: String { get set }
var priority: String { get set }
var reminder: String { get set }
var completed: String { get set }
var additionalDetails: String { get set }
}

class CloudKitTask: Task {
let record: CKRecord

init(record: CKRecord){
    self.record = record
}

init(task: Task){
    record = CKRecord(recordType: "Task")
    shortDescription = task.shortDescription
    className = task.className
    type = task.type
    dueDate = task.dueDate
    dueTime = task.dueTime
    priority = task.priority
    reminder = task.reminder
    completed = task.completed
    additionalDetails = task.additionalDetails

}

var className: String {
    get {
        return record.objectForKey("ClassName") as! String
    }
    set {
        record.setObject(newValue, forKey: "ClassName")
    }
}

var completed: String {
    get {
        return record.objectForKey("Completed") as! String
    }
    set {
        record.setObject(newValue, forKey: "Completed")
    }
}

var dueDate: String {
    get {
        return record.objectForKey("DueDate") as! String
    }
    set {
        record.setObject(newValue, forKey: "DueDate")
    }
}

var dueTime: String {
    get {
        return record.objectForKey("DueTime") as! String
    }
    set {
        record.setObject(newValue, forKey: "DueTime")
    }
}

var priority: String {
    get {
        return record.objectForKey("Priority") as! String
    }
    set {
        record.setObject(newValue, forKey: "Priority")
    }
}

var reminder: String {
    get {
        return record.objectForKey("Reminder") as! String
    }
    set {
        record.setObject(newValue, forKey: "Reminder")
    }
}

var shortDescription: String {
    get {
        return record.objectForKey("ShortDescription") as! String
    }
    set {
        record.setObject(newValue, forKey: "ShortDescription")
    }
}

var type: String {
    get {
        return record.objectForKey("Type") as! String
    }
    set {
        record.setObject(newValue, forKey: "Type")
    }
}

var additionalDetails: String {
    get {
        return record.objectForKey("AdditionalDetails") as! String
    }
    set {
        record.setObject(newValue, forKey: "AdditionalDetails")
    }
}

var id: String? {
    return record.recordID.recordName
}

var createdAt: NSDate {
    return record.creationDate!
}

var lastModifiedAt: NSDate {
    return record.modificationDate!
}
}
```

I'm fairly new to programming with Swift and can't seem to find an answer that fixes my problem, if you know what I am doing wrong or what I can do to fix it please do point me in the right direction your help is very much appreciated.

If you need to see any more of my code please do ask...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably meant here was to construct a `CloudKitTask` without first creating a `CKRecord`. In that case you should have an initializer for that:

```
convenience init() {
    self.init(record: CKRecord(recordType: "Task"))
}
```

Then you can use it:

```
func submitTask(){
    let task = CloudKitTask()
    task.shortDescription = self.txtShortDesc.text!
    task.type = self.txtType.text!
    task.reminder = self.txtReminder.text!
    task.priority = self.txtPriority.text!
    task.dueTime = self.txtDueTime.text!
    task.dueDate = self.txtDueDate.text!
    task.completed = "False"
    task.className = self.txtClass.text!
    task.additionalDetails = self.txtDetails.text
    print(task)
}
```